# How to unistall python3.5 and re-install python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on a google compute engine Debian instance. It currently has python3.5 but not python3.7. How would I uninstall python3.5 and re-install python3.7? Here is an example:

```
david@instance-py3:~$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
david@instance-py3:~$ python3.7
-bash: python3.7: command not found
```

I don't want to have both, but uninstall python3.5 before proceeding.

Comment: This link may be helpful for you, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062498/install-python-3-7-with-the-3-5-version-already-installed-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: You do not need to uninstall Python3.5 to install Python3.7, actually you might have some programs that need Python3.5, so just leave it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer follow this [link](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/)

1. You need to download python 3.7 first (example: You download to /usr/src/). [Click here to download](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/)
2. Then install prerequisites:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
>
> sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

3. Extract:

> cd /usr/src
>
> sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.0.tgz

4. Compile:

> cd Python-3.7.0
>
> sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
>
> sudo make altinstall

That's it.

Comment: It helped me. Thanks !